I have created a folder/package. two subpackages (first one=subpkg1 and second one=subpkg2) a file inisde subpkg1and import file from subpkg2. and

I am using VS code for learning java. I have created a folder/package(name=pkg). Then I created  two packages (first one=subpkg1 and second one=subpkg2) inisde the package. But I created a file (test1) inisde subpkg1 and import file (name= food) from subpkg2 then compile and run. I kept getting the error that pkg.subpkg2 doesn't exist (see the image)
I am expecting it to get the file imported. please answer it for vs code

The problem here is you only went to the "tr" package and compiled test.java. The restaurant.java file is neither compiled nor in the package.
Try first cd to the "Package" (containing both "fil" and "tr"), then use this command
javac -d {packageName} tr/test.java fil/restaurant.java

to compile both files and put the .class files to the same package (the "-d" command does so). If the package name you entered doesn't exist, it should be created under the Package folder. After this, use the following command
java -cp {packageName} Package.tr.test

or other commands to run the code.

are there any other way like run code button provided by code runner in vs code for simple program? note- run code button causes error where import of one class from subpackage is done to another class in another subpackage. I used Run Java button provided by  extension pack for java and it worked. but run java button gives error  while running some programs . both run code and run java button causes error in some field. is there any other option in vs code . or should i try other IDE

For this one, the run button will work easily because it builds the whole program instead of a single file. But indeed both run button and commands will produce weird errors sometimes, and this is where you need to step in and find solutions.
